# CustomBinding Handler render template for each item in array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have looked and haven't found much documentation on how to perform the following:

i want to create a slideshow custom knockout binding handler.  This handler should be able to be passed an array of images along with the id of a knockout template to be used for each item rendered in the slideshow.  The problem i am having is i cannot find any examples online that shows how to pass an observablearray to a custom binding, and have knockout render a dom element, using a knockout script template, for each item in the array onto the page.  Does anyone have any examples?

Binding Example

```
<div class="slideshow" data-bind="slideshow: { data: images, imageTemplate: 'rowTmpl' }">

      </div>
```

Template to be used for each item example

```
      <script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">
          <div class='product-image-container'>
              <figure class='product-image'>
                  <picture>
                      <img itemprop='image' alt='Image' data-bind='attr: { src: image.Url }' />
                      </picture>
                  <figcaption></figcaption>
                  </figure>
              </div>

      </script>
```

Any advice/help/examples is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the knockout docs help you with this? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html Under "Note 2: Using the “foreach” option with a named template"

Comment: No it does not.  I am creating a custom ko binding handler for a third party library that creates a slideshow.  Therefore that built in template binding is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to manage the functionality provided by `foreach` yourself, but it is much, much easier to use the [binding preprocessing](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html) feature. [Knockout Punches](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) also uses this feature to implement most of its functionality.

What you mentioned in the comments..

> Therefore that built in template binding is not suitable.

..makes little sense: if you rather implement template loading yourself, you can go back to plain ol' manually creating DOM elements & attach listeners to them.
Much wiser would be to integrate the template binding in your custom binding, albeit invisibly. With that, there's not even a need for either an `init` or `update` function:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideshow = {
  preprocess: function(value, name, addBinding) {
    var newBinding = value.replace('imageTemplate', 'name').replace('data', 'foreach');
    addBinding('template', newBinding);
    return value;
  }
};
```

Of course you can still add an init/update function, and 'parameterize' your binding (adding more options), and act upon them there.
You can find a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/yrv8cv26/1/.
I also added a simple Prev/next navigation to show how you can add functionality with simple DOM events afterwards.